# Best way to position randomly generated absolute divs as a grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have an app that generates a random number of divs that are always absolutely positioned. No, I can't make them relative due to other factors in the app.

Is there a way in CSS or JQuery to make these absolutely positioned divs grid-ified? So something like:

```
     X X X
     X X X
     X X X
     etc...
```

As of now, they come out like this:

```
     X
     X
     X
     etc...
```

I won't know how many divs will be in each query; could be 5, could be 80, could be 17, etc.

Comment: I can solve this, but can you please tell me why you can't use position relative? It would be great if you share the required code.

Comment: This app is built using react.js - a seating chart - where the seats have to be positioned a particular way etc. I've tried very damn way possible and only absolute position seems to work.

Comment: maybe try [Bootstrap and its grid system](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)?

Comment: not really a solution in this situation. Boostrap grid uses relative positioning...

Answer (score 0):

If you know the container's width, you can use this code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.x {
  position: absolute;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
  <div class="x">x</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var offset = 10;
  var offsetTop = 10;
  var _width = $("#container").width();
  console.log(_width);

  $('.x').each(function(e, item) {
    console.log($(item));
    $(item).offset({
      top: offsetTop,
      left: offset
    });
    offset += 20;

    if (offset >= _width) {
      offsetTop += 30;
      offset = 10;
    }
  })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm working with React.js, and react adds a unique HTML5 data attribute to each element (i.e, data-reactid), using SASS, I did this:

```
@for $i from 0 through 153 {
 $base: 865px;
 $inc: 150px;
.enrollments__inner > div[data-reactid$='#{$i}'] {
    position: absolute;
    @if $i >= 0 and $i <= 20 {
        left: (80 * $i) + px;
        top: $base;
    }
    @if $i >= 21 and $i <= 40 {
        left:  (80 * ($i - 21)) + px;
        top: $base + $inc;
    }
    @if $i >= 41 and $i <= 60 {
        left: (80 * ($i - 41)) + px;
        top: $base + ($inc * 2);
    }
    @if $i >= 61 and $i <= 80 {
        left: (80 * ($i - 61)) + px;
        top: $base + ($inc * 3);
    }
    @if $i >= 81 and $i <= 100 {
        left: (80 * ($i - 81)) + px;
        top: $base + ($inc * 4);
    }
    @if $i >= 101 and $i <= 121 {
        left: (80 * ($i - 101)) + px;
        top: $base + ($inc * 5);
    }
    @if $i >= 122 and $i <= 142 {
        left: (80 * ($i - 122)) + px;
        top: $base + ($inc * 6);
    }
    @if $i >= 143 and $i <= 153 {
        left: (80 * ($i - 143)) + px;
        top: $base + ($inc * 7);
    }
}
```

}